# Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at filename near text "input"; expecting ";"

Tags: verilog, quartus

Working with 2014 version of Quartus II software (web edition), I receive the error 10170 when compiling the following code:

```
module shifter16 (A, H_sel, H)
input [15:0]A;
input H_sel;
output [15:0]H;
reg [15:0] H;
always @ (A or H_sel)
begin
    if (H_sel)
        H={A[14:0],1'b0};
    else
        H={A[15],A[15:1]};
end
endmodule
```

Error received:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at shifter16.v(2) near text "input";  expecting ";"

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon at the end of the first line:

```
module shifter16 (A, H_sel, H);
```